# php sum values of multiple subarrays if subarrays are not the same length (not the same number of keys)

Tags: php, arrays, sum

Have such array (placed code here http://codepad.viper-7.com/mTqf6W)

```
Array
(
[17,bank stmt,1,23,3,2014] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [RecordDay] => 17
                [Amount] => 1.5
            )
    )
[17,invoice,2,17,3,2014] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [RecordDay] => 17
                [Amount] => 0.21
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [RecordDay] => 17
                [Amount] => 1
            )

    )


)
```

Want to get totals of `[Amount]` for each subarray. For the first subarray there is only one key, so Total equals to `[Amount]`. But for the second subarray there are 2 keys (may be more than 2 keys), so in some way need to sum all `[Amount]`

For `[17,bank stmt,1,23,3,2014]` would be 1.5, `[17,invoice,2,17,3,2014]` would be 1.21

Following some examples [PHP Array_Sum on multi dimensional array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404422/php-array-sum-on-multi-dimensional-array) trying to create code. Created

```
$values = array('Amount' => 0);
$counter = 0;
foreach ($temp_array as $key => $item) {
$values['Amount'] += $item[$counter]['Amount'];
$counter++;
}
```

Get error 'Notice: Undefined offset: 2'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have PHP 5.5+, this can be done with [`array_column()`](http://php.net/array_column) and [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/array_sum):

```
foreach ($array as $sub) {
    echo array_sum(array_column($sub, 'Amount'));
}
```

Use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) to extract all the amounts and then [`array_sum()`](http://php.net/array_sum) to sum the values in the array:

```
foreach ($array as $sub) {
    echo array_sum(array_map(function($item) {
        return $item['Amount'];
    }, $sub));
}
```

Output:

```
1.5
1.21
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/142465)